# calling a hash value from a method

Tags: ruby, class, hash

So I am trying to create a menu class that among other things displays prices.

I am trying to create a method (show_price) that displays the price

```
 class Menu

  def initialize menu =  { pepperoni: 50, vegetariana: 50, mexicana: 50, deluxe: 100 }
    @list = menu
  end


  def show_price item
    item = ":" + "#{item}"
    list[item]
  end


  attr_reader :list

end
```

sadly it just gives me nil, does anybody know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
def show_price item
  item = item.to_sym
  @list[item]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Menu
  attr_reader :list

  def initialize menu =  { "pepperoni"=> 50, "vegetariana"=> 50, "mexicana"=> 50, "deluxe"=> 100 }
    @list = menu
  end


  def show_price item
    @list[item]
  end

end

menu = Menu.new()
puts "Deluxe costs: #{menu.show_price("deluxe")}"
```